# Troubles with compliation of javafx project

Tags: java, javafx

So here we go.Got some problems with compilation of javafx project. I was doing whole project using VS code editor and at the end I need to compile and run it using console. And when i'm doing it by using this command i get next errors. so this classes are defined within bookingapp package but i dont use any javafx library in them and however i keep getting those errors.

```
D:\Vladislav_Sovostyanov_230103134\BookingApp>javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml src/bookingapp/App.java
src\bookingapp\App.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
    public static Consumer consumer;
                  ^
  symbol:   class Consumer
  location: class App
src\bookingapp\App.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    public static PersonData data1;
                  ^
  symbol:   class PersonData
  location: class App
src\bookingapp\App.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    public static PersonData data2;
                  ^
  symbol:   class PersonData
  location: class App
3 errors
```

i tried compiling like that `javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml src/bookingapp/*.java` all files are compiles but when i want to run it using this command `java --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml src/bookingapp/App` it gives `ClassNotFoundException` while in the directory there is App.class file

Comment: The `java` command requires a class name.  A file name is not a class name.  A class name is a package name, followed by `.`, followed by the declared name of a class (the word after `public class`).  You probably need to change `src/bookingapp/App` to `bookingapp.App`.

Comment: I don't advise doing Java development from the command line by directly calling the `javac` and `java` commands.  Especially if you are also using resources such as fxml, which I guess you might be because you have the `javafx.fxml` module on the module path.  Instead, it is better to use a build tool, such as Maven or Gradle, IMO.  Information on how to do that with a JavaFX application is at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Answer (score -1):

Your run-command searches for the main-method in `src/bookingapp/App.class` the other class-files need to be added to the `module-path` or the `classpath` at least (default module)

Why not packing your compiled class-files into a `jar`, then include the `jar` into the `module-path` and start the `main-app` via its fully qualified name (all packages upfront)